# Typescript removes Authorization header from POST and PATCH fetch requests

Tags: javascript, c#, typescript

I've built an API using C# that uses JWT tokens for authorization. On the frontend I store these tokens in local storage and get them, when creating a request. When creating GET or DELETE requests, everything works fine, and using `console.log()` I can see that fetch options have the Authorization header added. However when using POST or PATCH methods, the Authorization header is missing immediatly after adding it to the object. Here is my request method:

```
const send = async (apiOptions: ApiParams): Promise<FetchReturn> => {
    const accessToken = GetAccessToken()
    const options: ApiOptions = {
        method: apiOptions.method,
        headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`
        }
    }

    console.log(options)

    if (apiOptions.data) {
        options.headers = {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
        options.body = JSON.stringify(apiOptions.data)
    }

    const result = await fetch(`${getUrl()}/${apiOptions.path}`, options).then(res => res).catch(err => err)
    if (!result.ok) {
        if (IsExpired()) {
            const refreshResult = await fetch(`${getUrl()}/api/user/refresh`, {method: 'POST', headers:{
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }, body: JSON.stringify(GetRefreshRequest())}).then(res => res).catch(err => err)
            if (refreshResult.ok) {
                Login(JSON.parse(await refreshResult.text()))

                return await send(apiOptions)
            } else if (refreshResult.status === 401) {
                Logout()
                window.location.reload()
                return { code: 0, text: ""}
            }
        }
    }
    const text = await result.text()
    return { code: result.status, text: text }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose that in apiParams for POST you have property 'data' assigned, and later you have if-condition that completely replaces request headers object.
Change it to:

```js
    options.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';
```

To keep authorization in headers

Comment: Thanks, this worked. Though it raises the question, why the console.log() before I assign data shows, that the authorization header isn't there.

Comment: I think, I can answer you this. You are checking log in Browser - and it shows you actually something like {object}. Then you click on it to see its contents. The thing is that you see contents of object not for the moment it was put to log, but for the moment you open it. Change console.log(options) to console.log(Json.serialize(options)) and you'll see you authorization header

Answer (score 0):

The first time check your `apiOptions.data`

i think , its null when you call `POST/Patch` request

Just put `console.log("...")` In the if statement , Then try for resolve your Error

If your problem not resolved, put a replay under my post